# Get average value from lines with duplicate adresses

Tags: bash, shell, sed, tshark

I wrote a bash script that runs tshark and outputs the results to a logfile. I've trimmed it down to only show the MAC adress and the antenna strength. (Trying to use this to count # of people in the room / building)

Its output looks like this:

```
c8:85:50:xx:xxxx    -88,-92
d8:fc:93:xx:xxxx    -76,-76
d8:fc:93:xx:xxxx    -76,-76
d8:fc:93:xx:xxxx    -76,-76
7c:c5:37:xx:xxxx    -69,-69
7c:c5:37:xx:xxxx    -67,-67
80:e6:50:xx:xxxx    -86,-86
d8:fc:93:xx:xxxx    -77,-77
d8:fc:93:xx:xxxx    -77,-77
d8:fc:93:xx:xxxx    -79,-79
34:e2:fd:xx:xxxx    -82,-82
34:e2:fd:xx:xxxx    -82,-82
a0:f3:c1:xx:xxxx    -49,-49
a0:f3:c1:xx:xxxx    -61,-61
80:be:05:xx:xxxx    -75,-75
80:be:05:xx:xxxx    -75,-75
80:be:05:xx:xxxx    -77,-77
80:be:05:xx:xxxx    -76,-76
80:be:05:xx:xxxx    -80,-80
a0:f3:c1:xx:xxxx    -49,-49
a0:f3:c1:xx:xxxx    -59,-59
80:e6:50:xx:xxxx    -88,-88
f8:16:54:xx:xxxx    -61,-61
f8:16:54:xx:xxxx    -61,-61
34:e2:fd:xx:xxxx    -81,-81
34:e2:fd:xx:xxxx    -82,-82
```

As you can see, some signals are sent multiple times. I would like to get the average value per MAC adress. How would I go about doing this?

So this:

```
a0:f3:c1:xx:xxxx    -49,-49
a0:f3:c1:xx:xxxx    -59,-59
```

should become this:

```
a0:f3:c1:xx:xxxx    -54,-54
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use awk. Create a *parse* file with the following content:

```
BEGIN {} {    
print "Processing mac " $1 " with values " $2 
split($2, inputArray, ",")
strvalue = mapMac[$1];

if(strvalue != null){
    split(strvalue, value,",")
    print "    Current value for " $1 " is " strvalue;
    value[1] += inputArray[1];
    value[2] += inputArray[2];
    value[3]++;
}else{
    value[1] = inputArray[1];
    value[2] = inputArray[2];
    value[3] = 1;
}
strvalue = value[1]","value[2]","value[3];
print "    New value for " $1 " is " strvalue;
mapMac[$1] = strvalue;

}
END{ 
    for(item in mapMac){
        split(mapMac[item], value, ",")
        print item " ---> " value[1]/value[3] ", " value[2]/value[3]
    }
}
```

And assuming your input file is called input.txt, invoke awk like this:

```
awk -f parse input.txt
```

An you'll get the average per mac address:

```
a0:f3:c1:xx:xxxx ---> -54.5, -54.5
7c:c5:37:xx:xxxx ---> -68, -68
d8:fc:93:xx:xxxx ---> -76.8333, -76.8333
c8:85:50:xx:xxxx ---> -88, -92
...
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Just had to trim the output to only use 1 decimal with %.1f (for my purposes).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

sort -k 1 file | tr -s " " > output

mac="";
sig1total=0;
sig2total=0;
count=0;
while read -r line; do
    oldmac=$mac;
    mac=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f1);
    signal1=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f2 | cut -d "," -f1);
    signal2=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f2 | cut -d "," -f2);
#   echo "$mac : $signal1 : $signal2";      
    #if true, compute the average of the previous mac addresses
    if [ "$oldmac" != "$mac" ] && [ $count -gt 0 ] ; then
            sigavg1=$(echo "$sig1total / $count" | bc -lq);
            sigavg2=$(echo "$sig2total / $count" | bc -lq);
            echo "$oldmac $sigavg1,$sigavg2";
            sig1total=0;
            sig2total=0;
            count=0;
    fi

    sig1total=$(( $sig1total + $signal1 ));
    sig2total=$(( $sig2total + $signal2 ));
    count=$(( $count + 1 ));

done < output
```

I'm expecting a file named "file" with the format you provided above, it trims the extra spaces & sorts it by mac address. I then read each line, and if the mac address isn't the same as the mac address I saw on the previous line, I output the old mac address and calculate the sum. Otherwise, I just add the value of the signals on the currently read in line then increment the count.

The result output was this:

```
34:e2:fd:xx:xxxx -81.75000000000000000000,-81.75000000000000000000
7c:c5:37:xx:xxxx -68.00000000000000000000,-68.00000000000000000000
80:be:05:xx:xxxx -76.60000000000000000000,-76.60000000000000000000
80:e6:50:xx:xxxx -87.00000000000000000000,-87.00000000000000000000
a0:f3:c1:xx:xxxx -54.50000000000000000000,-54.50000000000000000000
c8:85:50:xx:xxxx -88.00000000000000000000,-92.00000000000000000000
d8:fc:93:xx:xxxx -76.83333333333333333333,-76.83333333333333333333
```

Note that you may need to install `bc` but everything else should be included in GNU core utils.